# What happens under-the-hood of these conditions?

Tags: php

Using switch:

```
switch($page){
    case 'dog':
    case 'cat':
    case 'robot':
    case 'default':{

        break;
    };
    default:{

        break;
    }
}
```

Using if:

```
if($page == 'dog' || $page == 'cat' || $page == 'robot' || $page == 'default'){

}else{

}
```

Using needle & haystack:

```
$pages = array('dog', 'cat', 'robot', 'default');
if(in_array($page, $pages)){

}else{

}
```

> I would like to know what is happening under-the-hood.

---

### average speeds:

- **needle** Execution time : 0.054877042770386 seconds
- **if** Execution time : 0.014014959335327 seconds
- **switch** Execution time : 0.0093550682067871 seconds

Comment: 200 Bounty will be awarded for this.

Comment: If you want to know which is faster: profile or benchmark. If you want to know what happens, dump the bytecode (VLD or DBG) and look at the [source](https://github.com/php/php-src). Asking for an in-deep explanation on all three is definitely too broad.

Comment: I would say that in_array() is slowest one, but... waiting for the answer... :)

Comment: @mario that is to advanced for me.

Comment: That benchmark isn't really generalizable; the runtime depends on which value was set and how many comparisons the switch or if had to run through. [Profiling is easy and pretty](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler). And you'll discover that you're [wasting effort](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) on microoptimizing such things - in comparison to the rest of your code (database optimization, reducing loops, etc.)

Comment: @mario i've developed a web application which in turn runs several conditions similar to these, i am looking to reduce the loading time of my application.

Comment: @Richard Other factors that can affect your applications loading speed include visual asset size (images, videos etc) and number/length of scripts. Look into [JavaScript minification](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS).

Comment: To @mario 's point, if you're doing it for one line of code, you're micro optimizing.  If you learn which things are fastest, and make them a habit in your coding, you're coding better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All scenarios output with VLD (PHP 5.6.4)

**switch**

```
number of ops:  31
compiled vars:  !0 = $page
line     #* E I O op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2     0  E >   EXT_STMT                                                 
         1        ASSIGN                                                   !0, 'default'
   3     2        NOP                                                      
   4     3        EXT_STMT                                                 
         4        CASE                                             ~1      !0, 'dog'
         5      > JMPZ                                                     ~1, ->7
   5     6    > > JMP                                                      ->10
         7    >   EXT_STMT                                                 
         8        CASE                                             ~1      !0, 'cat'
         9      > JMPZ                                                     ~1, ->11
   6    10    > > JMP                                                      ->14
        11    >   EXT_STMT                                                 
        12        CASE                                             ~1      !0, 'robot'
        13      > JMPZ                                                     ~1, ->15
   7    14    > > JMP                                                      ->18
        15    >   EXT_STMT                                                 
        16        CASE                                             ~1      !0, 'default'
        17      > JMPZ                                                     ~1, ->23
        18    >   NOP                                                      
   9    19        EXT_STMT                                                 
        20      > BRK                                                      1, ->30
  11    21*       EXT_STMT                                                 
        22*       JMP                                                      ->25
        23    >   EXT_STMT                                                 
        24      > JMP                                                      ->29
        25    >   NOP                                                      
  13    26        EXT_STMT                                                 
        27      > BRK                                                      1, ->30
  15    28*       JMP                                                      ->30
        29    > > JMP                                                      ->25
  16    30    > > RETURN                                                   1
```

**if**

```
number of ops:  16
compiled vars:  !0 = $page
line     #* E I O op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2     0  E >   EXT_STMT                                                 
         1        ASSIGN                                                   !0, 'default'
   3     2        EXT_STMT                                                 
         3        IS_EQUAL                                         ~1      !0, 'dog'
         4      > JMPNZ_EX                                         ~1      ~1, ->7
         5    >   IS_EQUAL                                         ~2      !0, 'cat'
         6        BOOL                                             ~1      ~2
         7    > > JMPNZ_EX                                         ~1      ~1, ->10
         8    >   IS_EQUAL                                         ~3      !0, 'robot'
         9        BOOL                                             ~1      ~3
        10    > > JMPNZ_EX                                         ~1      ~1, ->13
        11    >   IS_EQUAL                                         ~4      !0, 'default'
        12        BOOL                                             ~1      ~4
        13    > > JMPZ                                                     ~1, ->15
   5    14    > > JMP                                                      ->15
```

**needle & haystack**

```
number of ops:  17
compiled vars:  !0 = $page, !1 = $pages
line     #* E I O op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2     0  E >   EXT_STMT                                                 
         1        ASSIGN                                                   !0, 'default'
   3     2        EXT_STMT                                                 
         3        INIT_ARRAY                                       ~1      'dog'
         4        ADD_ARRAY_ELEMENT                                ~1      'cat'
         5        ADD_ARRAY_ELEMENT                                ~1      'robot'
         6        ADD_ARRAY_ELEMENT                                ~1      'default'
         7        ASSIGN                                                   !1, ~1
   4     8        EXT_STMT                                                 
         9        EXT_FCALL_BEGIN                                          
        10        SEND_VAR                                                 !0
        11        SEND_VAR                                                 !1
        12        DO_FCALL                                      2  $3      'in_array'
        13        EXT_FCALL_END                                            
        14      > JMPZ                                                     $3, ->16
   6    15    > > JMP                                                      ->16
   9    16    > > RETURN                                                   1
```

as you can see the switch actually has the most ops, but is the quickest in your test case (Would be interested to see it, as i imagine each of these methods can be the "Best" in a certain case)

While ops are not a standard amount of work, they do give an indication.

**A little comparison**

Switch uses alot of `CASE` (check 2 values are equal) and `JMPZ` (Jump if address is Zero).

If statements use `IS_EQUAL`, which is similar to case, with the exception that the second value must be a constant. I would assume this would slow down the check as there is now 2 variables which can be checked. (Your benchmark results seem to agree with this)

The next uses a function call. Functions are usually considered slow in PHP 
https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/df29df7ec40cf7950a98f36bfa99ef19f0950309/ext/standard/array.c#L1595

is the C source of the function, which has different logic per type of variable. Assuming we are using strings, the array is looped and checked each value with

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/213b49620d24ebebe3cf19787ee6e3448d27d046/Zend/zend_operators.h#L712

Returning early if possible.

Benchmark script

```
$max_checks = 1000000;

$bench = -microtime(true);
for($i = 0;$i < $max_checks; $i++) {
  switch($page){
    case 'dog':
    case 'cat':
    case 'robot':
    case 'default':{
       break;
     };
    default:{

      break;
    }
  }
}
echo "\nSwitch took " . (microtime(true) + $bench);

$bench = -microtime(true);


for($i = 0;$i < $max_checks; $i++) {
  $page == 'dog' || $page == 'cat' || $page == 'robot' || $page == 'default';
}
echo "\nif took " . (microtime(true) + $bench);


$pages = array('dog', 'cat', 'robot', 'default');

$bench = -microtime(true);
for($i = 0;$i < $max_checks; $i++) {
  (in_array($page, $pages));
}

echo "\nneedle haystack took " . (microtime(true) + $bench);
```

Passing in `$page = 'dog';`

```
Switch took 0.31698203086853
if took 0.18721604347229
needle haystack took 1.5701420307159
```

passing in `$page = 'default';`

```
Switch took 0.46866297721863
if took 0.40072298049927
needle haystack took 1.6747360229492
```

passing in `$page = 'no match';`

```
Switch took 0.52629804611206
if took 0.40276217460632
needle haystack took 1.6838929653168
```

Im not sure what input you used but if and switch are similar for me (edge for switch for being more readable)

Edit:

1 more test case which is faster.
using if with `===`

This replaces `IS_EQUAL` calls with `IS_IDENTICAL`

There is a slight speed up

for all test cases

```
if      took 0.43217587471008
if(===) took 0.39284706115723
```

List of opcodes
http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.list.php

**Edit number 2**

Because im testing PHP 7 RC3 anyway.

Benchmarks re run (on the same machine)

`$page = 'dog';`

```
Switch took 0.018393993377686
if took 0.030646085739136
if(===) took 0.036449909210205
needle haystack took 0.045974969863892
```

`$page = 'default';`

```
Switch took 0.040921211242676
if took 0.085216999053955
if(===) took 0.1043848991394
needle haystack took 0.052649974822998
```

`$page = 'no match';`

```
Switch took 0.059795141220093
if took 0.080615997314453
if(===) took 0.10486197471619
needle haystack took 0.049200057983398
```

With PHP 7  the needle and haystack looks best

Comment: Wow this was an extraordinary answer, tomorrow i will award a bounty. wow. This was very clear and helpful. especially the Assembly.